# Debian assigned hundreds IPv6 public address

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ipv6

My Debian have IPv6 assignment problem. The interface assigned hundreds IPv6 public address:

```
$ ip addr | grep -c '2409:'
219
```

Using `ip addr` check IPv6 addresses:

```
3: enp11s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:36:93:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp11s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2409:8a50:a4e:92f0:6174:3f62:57cf:ba6a/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258842sec preferred_lft 85861sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a4e:92f0:f49d:44ca:8557:3ca5/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 258842sec preferred_lft 172442sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a46:c400:6174:3f62:57cf:ba6a/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258843sec preferred_lft 85861sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a46:c400:7541:7da1:5434:1741/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 258843sec preferred_lft 172443sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a46:c400:d05e:8af5:f6cf:f42f/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258554sec preferred_lft 85860sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a4e:92f0:d05e:8af5:f6cf:f42f/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258842sec preferred_lft 85860sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a4e:92f0:5999:8fc7:475b:ccef/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258303sec preferred_lft 85572sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a46:c400:5999:8fc7:475b:ccef/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258554sec preferred_lft 85572sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a46:c400:d9d3:ef05:bb58:ca07/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258137sec preferred_lft 85321sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a4e:92f0:d9d3:ef05:bb58:ca07/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258303sec preferred_lft 85321sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a4e:92f0:71c8:2bc:9942:9d25/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258051sec preferred_lft 85155sec
    inet6 2409:8a50:a46:c400:71c8:2bc:9942:9d25/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 258137sec preferred_lft 85155sec
    .......
```

and the Kernel message shows:

```
[496922.494943] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[497266.149336] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[497287.754771] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[497581.736350] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[498100.833291] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[498118.774008] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[498690.290277] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[499141.642258] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[499586.227054] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[499742.201967] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[499901.453946] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[499961.327580] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[500430.519108] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[500727.481891] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[500913.499238] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[500978.223144] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[501374.991352] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[501561.471323] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[501958.160961] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[502102.048465] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[502546.680738] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[502767.658846] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[503042.022824] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[505438.052608] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[505816.211563] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[506099.932168] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[506448.276145] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[506632.626997] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[507026.426232] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[507331.850194] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[507364.491312] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[507578.809108] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[507628.593994] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
........
```

And the `/etc/init.d/networking restart` not working.
What cause that? and how to solve it?

thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network manager registering thousands of IPv6 addresses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500953/network-manager-registering-thousands-of-ipv6-addresses)

Comment: thank you @FelixJN, the same question, but i dont want to disable my ipv6 due to i have only ipv6 public address ^^) and other devices have no the problem like openwrt or android phones.

Comment: Well, you could delete the IPv6 addresses easily with a script. But as long as the cause is not tackled, I assume they'll be regenerated. One reason could be that temporary addresses are activated as privacy enhancement. What is the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/use_tempaddr`?

Comment: @FelixJN the result is 1, it seems solved when i tried disable privacy in network manager, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reason: The [IPv6 privacy](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPv6#Privacy_extensions) is activated. This generates a separate IPv6 address per connection so the hardware-based part of your IPv6 address may not be used to identify the machine in use.

In debian, the setting can be seen from

```
$cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/use_tempaddr
```

Where

- `0` - disabled
- `1` - enabled, prefer public address
- `2` - enabled, prefer temporary address
- `-1` - unset/unnknown, use default

**Disable in NetworkManager**

Check in either `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/ip6-privacy.conf` for

```
[connection]
ipv6.ip6-privacy=2
```

or in the individual connections in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/connection.example` for

```
[ipv6]
ip6-privacy=2
```

Set these values to `0` and best also send an

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/use_tempaddr
```

just to be sure and then restart NetworkManager.

Now that the temporary address generation is disabled, check if the addresses are removed. If not, deleting all addresses would work like here:

```
#/bin/bash
ip a | grep global | grep -o '2409.[^ ]*' | while read address ; do
  ip del $address dev enp11s0
done
ip addr add $address dev enp11s0
```

I.e. just match global IPv6 addresses, delete them all, but for the last one reactivate it.

PS: I am pretty sure that with the right subnetmask you might actually skip the loop ....

Comment: thank you, that works!